A question about characteristic surface (PDE)
Recently, I'm studying about characteristic surface in "Partial Differential Equations, an Introduction", SECOND Edition, by Walter A. Strauss.
This is his definition:

But I got some problem in the defintion. In the book, Mr. Strauss said $∇γ(x_0)$ and $v_0$ are parallel. I want to give an example for the definition. To avoid the difficulty of plotting, I set the point in two dimension(i.e. the space-time is 3D).
The result is the above figure.

S is a plane in 3D space-time, and $S_0$ is a straight line in {t=0}. And I found $∇γ(x_0)$ and $v_0$ are not parallel. Why?
